# Is there a way to publish org-mode files as html files and preserve the asterisk section markers?

Tags: emacs, blogs, org-mode

Basically I'm wondering if there is a org to blog suite that allows visitors to a org-created blog to press the TAB key and see expanded sections where they'd be expanded in an org-mode doc.  If this is a standard feature and a trivial question I'm sorry, I couldn't find this on any of the standard sites.

Answer (score 0):

http://orgmode.org/worg/code/org-info-js/ is the closest equivalent I know of. It is ligthly described in the manual: http://orgmode.org/org.html#JavaScript-support